# Why are Kotlin interfaces "not open"?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

In Kotlin 1.4.30, when I type

```
open interface I
```

the Kotlin compiler warns me that `modifier 'open' is redundant for 'interface'`. This makes complete sense: Of course interfaces are open, otherwise they would be useless.

However, the reflection library seems to contradict this:

```
interface I
println(I::class.isOpen) // prints 'false'
```

How does this make sense? The [KDoc of `isOpen`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-open.html) is very brief:

> `true` if this class is open.

**What exactly is the definition of "open" in Kotlin?**
I thought it meant "open to the possibility of being sub-typed by classes outside this file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The methods `isFinal`, `isOpen`, `isAbstract`, `isSealed` were designed such that only one of them returns true for all `KClass` instances.**

Source: [this comment in KT-19850](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19850#focus=Comments-27-2382240.0-0).

Since interfaces are abstract, `I::class.isAbstract == true`. Combined with the above design goal, `I::class.isOpen == false` results.

Please upvote [KT-19850](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19850) to help getting this surprising behavior fixed.

Comment: Interfaces being abstract but not open make sense when you consider what it implies. You can instantiate open classes while it's impossible for abstract ones.

Comment: @Pawel I'm not convinced by your explanation: if "open" implied "can be instantiated", I would expect `open interface` to throw a compiler error. Instead, I am getting a warning that tells me "you don't need to write `open`, that's already implied by `interface`".

Comment: @Pawel Also, a `sealed class` has `isAbstract == false` even though it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Yes, I understand abstract to be a superset of open. Open does not imply "instantiable".